# Magento - Change quantity label text to hours and have a dropdown

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Need help on how to change the label "quantity" to "hours" and have a drop down. I have tier pricing on that particular product. I need to replace the text "quantity" to hours on that particular product alone. Help required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programatically in this way:

1. Add a custom phtml file for addtocart part under: app/design/frontend/[your_template_package_name]/[your_template_name]/template/catalog/product/view/**addtocart_custom.phtml**

with this content:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Hours:') ?></label>
            <select class="input-text qty" name="qty" id="qty">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Add on your product page in Magento admin the following layout update under Product details->Design->Custom layout update:

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/addtocart_custom.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thank Alain. Actually it worked the way I wanted. Only issue is displays both quantity and hours and two add to cart buttons. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: See the edited xml (last part). I have made some changes.. It should work now.

Comment: Instead of using reference name "product.info.addto" I replaced with "product.info.addtocart" removed the additional add to cart button

Answer (score 2):

To change label navigate to `Backend > catalog > attribute > manage attribute` Search for your targeted attribute. And `edit` on the left side on attribute `information section > Manage Label/options` and there you will find titles section and change the label.

Regarding changing attribute type to dropdown from `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` once you assign and save an attribute you cannot change there after.

**Edit**

To change for only one product check for it and if is true print other label.

```
$_product->getAttributeText('quantity')
```

Comment: This changes the option for global. I need to change for single particular product alone

Comment: on which page are you willing to change. You don't have that feature, but there are ways to do while populating...

Comment: How to achieve that?

Comment: i asked you above in which page you want to change ? is it product detail or listing ?

Comment: i have updated my answer you can check for the attribute label value and instead of global, you can print other. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

in my case (magento ce 1.9.2) the path to addtocart.phtml is:

```
app/design/frontend/YOURTEMPLATE/default/template/catalog/product/view
```

replace the word "Quantity" with your word(s) in a line (in my case - line# 32) that starts with:

```
<label for="qty">
```

gl,
H